# Environment variables are not getting expanded in JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to integrate a javaagent for application monitoring. I'm using docker and I've setup an OpenJDK base image which is inherited by other application images.

Since javaagent requires a path to the jar file, for maintenance purposes I've defined the path in the base image as another env variable(`AGENT_PATH`) and I want to reuse the same env variable across all my app images. For some reason the environment variable isn't picked and the application container exits with error.

Base Image's Dockerfile

```
AGENT_PATH=/agent/agent.jar
```

This is how I've configured `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` in application's Dockerfile.

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:$AGENT_PATH + other JVM options"
```

This is the error message

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:$AGENT_PATH
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : $AGENT_PATH
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Why is `AGENT_PATH` not getting substituted properly ?

I've grepped through Hotspot implementation for understanding. I've found [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l2778).

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the Docker step. If you use [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) step the variables processing is not supported:

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `RUN [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `RUN [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]`. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

Comment: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is injected via Helm Chart into a Kubernetes Deployment. Please excuse my ignorance, but will it be any different ?

Comment: @goutham It's not working with you current approach. I don't know you entire deployment pipeline, sorry can't help here.

Comment: Yes, it's not working for me, The wierd part is, when I exec into the running container(by hardcoding JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS) I could see  the value for `AGENT_PATH` env.

Answer (score 0):

In dockerfiles, all directives require a certain codeword. Assigning an environment variable is no different from this and needs the `ENV` codeword (read [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)).

Using this, the excerpt of your dockerfile should read

```
ENV AGENT_PATH=/agent/agent.jar
```

Comment: I didn't mention it explicitly but I did use ENV construct in my base image. 
```
ENV AGENT_PATH=/agent/agent.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue where the environment variables set in the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS were not getting substituted. So I had to mention those variables as -D parameters along with java command.

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$KeyStore_Secret .....
```

You can check if that is the case by hardcoding the values in the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and it should work. Meanwhile, I am still looking at the reason for this.